# Каким образом можно с помощью \b реализовать скрытие вводимого значения?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь найти информацию по /b, сферы применения, но кроме того как затереть вводимые значения другими символами не нашел. Как можно данное затирание реализовать?

Comment: Чтобы ничего не печатолось в консоли при чтении символа, можно просто использовать `Console.ReadKey(true)`, он будет перехватывать нажатие. Ответ по ссылке вверху, там есть ссылка на еще один ответ, где есть решение по вводу пароля звездочками в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

`\b` сдвигает курсор влево. Так например

```cs
Console.WriteLine("abc\b\b12"); // a12
```